# What is wrong with this approach to easy trig question?

Tags: trigonometry

Solve this: $\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\sin x} = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} $

Of course this is true:
$\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\sin x} = \tan\dfrac{x}{2} = \dfrac{\sqrt3}{3}$

But why is this approach invalid:
$\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{3} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} $

So it follows $\sin x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\cos x = 1 - \dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{2}{3}$.
Consequently, $\tan x = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

I'm embarrassed I didn't know how to explain why the approach above is wrong. Please advise.

Comment: "So it follows". I don't see why it should. You've *just* said that $\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}=\frac{\frac13}{\frac1{\sqrt3}}$, where it is apparent that $\sqrt3\ne\frac13$ and $3\ne\frac1{\sqrt3}$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I don't think he is saying that.  I think he is using the fact that $\frac{a}{b}$ can be written as $\frac{\frac{1}{b}}{\frac{1}{a}}$ since this is just $\frac{1}{b} \div \frac{1}{a}= \frac{1}{b} \cdot a=\frac{a}{b}$ (Assuming $a$ and $b$ are not 0.)

Comment: @randomgirl It doesn't matter if he used middle school algebra or if he made a three-page synthetic geometry theorem to prove it. Fact is that there are two mathematics in this post. Friday-mathematics, which allows him to write the same quantity as a fraction of two different pairs of numbers, and Saturday-mathematics which makes him wonder what's wrong with saying that from $\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{\frac13}{\frac1{\sqrt3}}$ the assertion $1-\cos x=\frac13\land \sin x=\frac1{\sqrt3}$ follows.

Comment: I just thought you were saying the equality $\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}=\frac{\frac13}{\frac1{\sqrt3}} $was wrong.
@saucy o'path .

Comment: What follows is that $\sin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} k$ and $1-\cos x =\frac13k$ *for some non-zero $k$*. You can determine $k$ thusly: $$1=\sin^2x+\cos^2x=\frac13 k^2+\left(1-\frac13k\right)^2\quad\to\quad \frac29 k\left(2k-3\right)=0\quad\to\quad k =\frac32$$

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ does not imply that $a=c$ and $b=d$.

If $\sin x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\cos x=\frac{2}{3}$, then $\sin^2x+\cos^2x\ne1$.

Comment: This seems like a paradox to me. If c=a and d=b then a/b = a/b which is a necessarily true identity.

Comment: It is true that if $c=a$ and $d=b$ then $a/b = a/b$. The converse is not.  $10/3=20/6$, but $10\ne20$ and $3\ne6$.

Comment: Ok we agree  "If c = a AND d = b THEN a/b = a/b". Converse of this is "If a/b = a/b THEN a=c AND b= d" which could be true?

Comment: @Quesop in general converse statements are not necessarily true.

Comment: It could be true. But it also could be false. As it does not satisfy $\sin^2 x+\cos^2x=1$, it cannot be true in this case.  We have $\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\frac{1/3}{1/\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1/2}{\sqrt{3}/2}$, but we cannot have $(1-\cos x,\sin x)=(\sqrt{3},3)$, $(1-\cos x,\sin x)=(1/3,1/\sqrt{3})$ and $(1-\cos x,\sin x)=(1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)$ being true at the same time.

Comment: Ok so the question defines $(1-\cos x,\sin x)=(\sqrt{3},3)$ So the alternative approach is saying a and b have two (potentially infinite) values each which cannot be true by definition of the question? Or is the approach wrong only because of the circular/pythagorean trigonometric identity requirement?

Comment: $\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ does not imply that $(1-\cos x,\sin x)=(\sqrt{3},3)$. But you may say that  $(1-\cos x,\sin x)=(\sqrt{3}k,3k)$ for some non-zero constant $k$. This implies that $(\cos x,\sin x)=(1-\sqrt{3}k,3k)$. As $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, we have $1=(1-\sqrt{3}k)^2+(3k)^2=1-2\sqrt{3}k+12k^2$ This fixes the value of $k$ and the values of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.

Comment: "Ok so the question defines $(1−\cos x,\sin x)=(\sqrt3,3)$". It certainly does not.

Answer (score 0):

$$1-cos x=1-(1-2sin^2\frac{x}{2})=2 sin^\frac{x}{2}$$

$$\frac{1- cos x}{sin x}=\frac {2 sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{2 sin \frac{x}{2} cos \frac{x}{2}}=tan \frac{x}{2}=\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}= \frac {1}{\sqrt 3}= \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}}=\tan \frac{\pi}{6}$$

⇒ $$\frac {x}{2}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

⇒ $$x=\frac {\pi}{3}$$

is primitive root and general solution is $x=2k \pi+\frac{\pi}{3}$.